# Problems with Arcsynthesis OpenGL 3.3 tutorials - MAKE error

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, makefile

I've been following arcsynthesis(arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) tutorial and come across with the following errors during make. I used premake4 gmake to generate makefiles.

```
==== Building Tut 13 Basic Impostor (debug) ====
Creating obj/Debug/Tut 13 Basic Impostor
BasicImpostor.cpp
Linking Tut 13 Basic Impostor
/usr/bin/ld: ../glsdk/freeglut/lib/libfreeglutD.a(freeglut_window.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XGetWindowAttributes'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Tut 13 Basic ImpostorD] Error 1
make: *** [Tut 13 Basic Impostor] Error 2
```

Here's my makefile. I am not sure if this is what you were asking for, as I am beginner in Ubuntu:

```
# GNU Make solution makefile autogenerated by Premake
# Type "make help" for usage help

ifndef config
  config=debug
endif
export config

PROJECTS := framework Tut\ 13\ Basic\ Impostor Tut\ 13\ Geometry\ Impostor

.PHONY: all clean help $(PROJECTS)

all: $(PROJECTS)

framework: 
    @echo "==== Building framework ($(config)) ===="
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C ../framework -f Makefile

Tut\ 13\ Basic\ Impostor: framework
    @echo "==== Building Tut 13 Basic Impostor ($(config)) ===="
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C . -f Tut\ 13\ Basic\ Impostor.make

Tut\ 13\ Geometry\ Impostor: framework
    @echo "==== Building Tut 13 Geometry Impostor ($(config)) ===="
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C . -f Tut\ 13\ Geometry\ Impostor.make

clean:
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C ../framework -f Makefile clean
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C . -f Tut\ 13\ Basic\ Impostor.make clean
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C . -f Tut\ 13\ Geometry\ Impostor.make clean

help:
    @echo "Usage: make [config=name] [target]"
    @echo ""
    @echo "CONFIGURATIONS:"
    @echo "   debug"
    @echo "   release"
    @echo ""
    @echo "TARGETS:"
    @echo "   all (default)"
    @echo "   clean"
    @echo "   framework"
    @echo "   Tut 13 Basic Impostor"
    @echo "   Tut 13 Geometry Impostor"
    @echo ""
    @echo "For more information, see http://industriousone.com/premake/quick-start"
```

Comment: Can you show the actual linker / object input parameters. Generally this results if you forget to link against a dynamic shared object required by something else... `-lX11` would almost certainly fix your problem. Some toolchains are extremely picky about the order you indicate dependent libraries as well (e.g. `-lX11` needs to come after `-lfreeglutD`).

Comment: That is not quite what is necessary; the contents of `Tut\ 13\ Basic\ Impostor.make` are what are important. That said, this issue is probably going to pop up for the **Geometry Impostor** build target as well once you get **Basic Impostor** working.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was just as you said. I added -lX11 to Geometry Impostor and Basic Impostor, and it worked! If you want please add this comment as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `-lX11` switches in your Makefiles, and this particular linker error is telling you that **libfreeglutD** depends on the dynamic shared object (DSO): *libX11.so*.

You will have to add this to the two makefiles: `Tut\ 13\ Basic\ Impostor.make` and `Tut\ 13\ Geometry\ Impostor.make`. It is very likely that in order to run other tutorials from Arcsynthesis you are going to have to do the same.